# how to save multiple bitmap images to internal storage and read into a list activity

Tags: android

How can i write a bitmap image to internal storage, (prefer if i can save the bit map in my Own Directory ex "/data/data/com.myapp/myfolder/img1.png") i need to save the multiple images into this directory.after saving multiple images to above directory i need to show the saved images in a list activity,

Method Use to save the Image to internal Storage

```
private void saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage,String filename){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("myfolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath=new File(directory,filename+ ".png");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
           // fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            System.out.println("mypath = "+mypath);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Read the images from Internal Storage.

```
 private File [] loadInternalImages(){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("myfolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File[] imageList = directory.listFiles();
        if(imageList == null){
            imageList = new File[0];
        }
        Log.i("My","ImageList Size = "+imageList.length);
        return imageList;
    }
```

Regards,
Sam

Comment: What have you done so far ? What troubles do you have ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the methods i'm using,i'm getting zero list size when i read the internal storage.

Comment: do some further investigation - check if your bitmaps are correctly saved in the internal storage. Check if your directory is created, in your code you're not creating it.

Comment: I can get the absolute path to saved image and can read the height of the image. System.out.println("mypath.getAbsolutePath() = "+mypath.getAbsolutePath());
      BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mypath.getAbsolutePath(), bfo);
      System.out.println("bm.getHeight = "+bm.getHeight()); problem is   System.out.println("cw.fileList().length = "+cw.fileList().length); return zero,

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try imageList.size instead of imageList.length to check if your list is correctly fullfilled.